# Matlab function memory consuption

Tags: matlab, memory

How can I determine the peak of memory consumption in some function in Matlab?

for example

```
A= rand(1000,1000); %A takes N Mb
func(A); % some operation on A because of which memory consumption can grow
```

Comment: start reading from http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/memory.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start the profiler with the memory switch:

```
profile -memory
```

which I think is actually undocumented...Works on R2010, can anyone verify that it still works on R2013a?

Anyway, when profiling with this switch, the profiler GUI will now include basic memory info, of which I think you'll find the last column ("Peak Memory") most interesting:

[image: Profiler with meminfo]

Comment: Works in R2013a as well. Results are a bit interesting though, some functions get negative self memory and values in all four memory columns vary a lot from run to run even in my very simple tests.

Comment: @erikced,Do u know what is the meaning of negative self memory ??